# Can I create web Service to call Servlets?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am new to Web Services. I need to create a web service interface for an existing application that is made of Servlets and JSPs.

I am unable to proceed that how I can create a web service for Servlet.

Any pointers, e-books and example code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), it is Sun's JAX-RS implementation for building RESTful Web services

There is a good and simple example with source code [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/), it shouldn't take more than 10-15 minutes to do

Comment: Can you please suggest me some link in which a simple Hello World type Web Service is developed using Restful Web Service to call Servlets.

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer. This is the one I learned from, good and simple